# Execute a set of commands in order, sequentially with ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, reactiveui

I have a `ViewModel` with some `ReactiveCommands` that user can invoke manually.

```
CommandA
CommandB
CommandC
```

So the user can invoke only **B**, or **A** first, and then **C**.

The problem is that there is that **I want to create another command that runs them in order**, from A to C. They shouldn't run in parallel, but **sequentially**.

How can I do a command of the given characteristics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want them executed sequentially, [`ReactiveCommand.CreateCombined`](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/controlling-executability) isn't really a good fit. However, you could create something similar to [CombinedReactiveCommand](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/50403240c792d6d870fbe74961d5df297b4a1f2e/src/ReactiveUI/ReactiveCommand.cs#L937) to work for your situation.

Reactive commands can be executed manually by calling `ReactiveCommand<TParam,TResult>.Execute`, which returns an `IObservable<TResult>` that returns a single value. Therefore, a very basic implementation could just chain it to other execute calls with `SelectMany`:

```
ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() =>
    CommandA.Execute()
        .SelectMany(_ => CommandB.Execute())
        .SelectMany(_ => CommandC.Execute()));
```

If all of your commands have the same type, it could be made more generic:

```
var commands = new[] { CommandA, CommandB, CommandC };
ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() =>
    commands.Aggregate(
        Observable.Return(Unit.Default),
        (acc, cur) => acc.SelectMany(_ => cur.Execute())));
```

However, this does not take into consideration the other things CombinedReactiveCommand handles, such as `CanExecute` and `ThrownExceptions`. If you need to handle those, then you might consider rolling your own CombinedReactiveCommand.

Comment: Whoops, it seems that RxUI 8.3.1 doesn't expose the Execute method for ReactiveCommand. I'm getting red squiggles: 'ReactiveCommand' does not contain a definition for 'Execute' and no extension method 'Execute' accepting a first argument of type 'ReactiveCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: The base class `ReactiveCommand` doesn't implement the `Execute` method itself. It's on the generic version of the class `ReactiveCommand<TParam,TResult>`. I've updated my answer to make this more clear.

Answer (score 5):

Import System.Reactive.Linq, now you can:

```
{
    await CommandA.Execute();
    await CommandB.Execute();
    await CommandC.Execute();
}
```

System.Reactive.Linq makes IObservable as awaitable.

Comment: This is super handy! For the sake of example, I've used this answer in a custom an scripting pad. Each time the user presses the **Compile** button, it does 2 things: Save + Compile. The `SaveAndCompile` comand is defined as the following 
```SaveAndCompile = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () =>
            {
                await Save.Execute();
                await Compile.Execute();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am asuming, that your commands are of type `ReactiveCommand<Unit,Unit>` so, you can do this:

```
public class MyCoolViewModel
{
   bool runSequentially = false;

   public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Command { get; set; }
   public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Command2 { get; set; }
   public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Command3 { get; set; }
   public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> CommandwhoInvokesOtherCommands { get; set; }


   public MyCoolViewModel()
   {

       Command = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<Unit, Unit>(async _ =>
       {    
        runSequentially= false;
        Console.WriteLine("Start 1");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("End 1");
        return Unit.Default;
       });
      Command2 = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<Unit, Unit>(async _ =>
      {
        runSequentially = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Start 2");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("End 2");
        return Unit.Default;
      });

    Command3 = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<Unit, Unit>(async _ =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start 3");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("End 3");
        return Unit.Default;
    });

    CommandwhoInvokesOtherCommands = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<Unit, Unit>(async _ =>
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Invoking other commands");
          runSequentially = true;
          await Task.Delay(1000);
          Console.WriteLine("End");
          return Unit.Default;
      });

            /*Command 1, 2 and 3 only will run if flag is set to true*/
    CommandwhoInvokesOtherCommands.Where(_ => runSequentially).InvokeCommand(Command);
    Command.Where(_ => runSequentially).InvokeCommand(Command2);
    Command2.Where(_ => runSequentially).InvokeCommand(Command3);

    //Observable.Return(Unit.Default).InvokeCommand(CommandwhoInvokesOtherCommands);//for test purposes

}
}
```

The utility method InvokeCommand will call another command when a command returns, so this method plus a where clause will do the trick.

I hope this help you
Regards