# How to sequentially run Tasks and put the result in IObservable

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

In my ViewModel I would like to do couple of things and would like to update the status as things are done.

Kent Boogaart's book suggested to use Observable to show the progress. I am now stuck at how to do multiple pieces of work, say in `Task`s, and tick the observable. I attempted the `Concat` operator but all the `Task`s get started immediately and not one after another.

```
public class StartupViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public string Status { [ObservableAsProperty]get; }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit,string> LoadedCommand { get; set; }
    public StartupViewModel()
    {
        var progress = Observable.Concat(
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                return "hello";
            }).ToObservable(),
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                return "cip";
            }).ToObservable(),
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                return "2040";
            }).ToObservable()
        );

        LoadedCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() => progress);
        LoadedCommand
            .ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.Status, "Starting up, please be patient");
    }
}
```

Comment: One option is using SelectMany like stated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51050913

Comment: Why do you want to run tasks one after another? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of using tasks?

Comment: Often they are used to avoid ui contention not just concurrency Enigmativity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are starting all of the tasks inside the construction of `Concat`. `Concat` is doing the right thing and grabbing the result from all the completed tasks. What you want to do is wrap the tasks in `Obserable.Defer` so they aren't started all at once, but only as they are subscribed to by the `Concat` operator:

```
var progress = Observable.Concat(
  Observable.Defer (() => Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); return 1; }).ToObservable()),
  Observable.Defer (() => Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); return 2; }).ToObservable())
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Potentially you could something like

```cs
return Observable.Create<string>(async (obs, cancellationToken) =>
{
   obs.OnNext(await Task1(cancellationToken));
   obs.OnNext(await Task2(cancellationToken));
   obs.OnNext(await Task3(cancellationToken));
   obs.OnCompleted();
});
```

Comment: How would you return a value when Tasks get completed?

Comment: Updated for that case.

Comment: You could also do a try/catch and do a OnError(ex) too.